# Why I'm forced to agree to PayPal terms even when I'm not using PayPal?

Tags: paypal, ebay

I'm trying to purchase something on eBay and I'm forced to accept PayPal terms, despite I'm not using PayPal to pay for the item. So it doesn't make any sense.

> I agree to the [PayPal terms](https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/ua/privacywax-full) and [Privacy Policy](https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/ua/privacy-full). PayPal provides this payment service. PayPal account not required.

[image: eBay Checkout - PayPal terms]

Is there any way to purchase the item on eBay by not accepting the PayPal terms?

Comment: Probably not, since I expect that eBay is using PayPal for credit card processing.

Comment: There is a "tell us what you think" link. You could certainly give them your thoughts on having to agree to the PayPal ToS when you're not using PayPal to pay.

Comment: I wish to tell them about it, but there is no any human support available or chat.

Comment: Follow the link. I'm sure there's some sort of feedback form you can fill out. I expect this is just like every EULA that no one reads. If you want to move forward, you need to agree with the terms. If you don't agree, then you need to find a different way to get the item.